# Mediatr pipeline behaviour not being called in .NET Framework MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, mediatr

I have created a custom pipeline behaviour class for the MediatR pipeline to attempt to handle some authorisation routines that I need to run. However, it seems to be getting ignored and does not seem to be getting called in the chain of execution.

I then created a very basic test piepline behaviour class just to see if that gets hit and had the exact same issue.

All of the examples I have seen have been within a .NET Core application, whereas I am using **.NET Framework 4.6 (MVC 5)** and **Unity (IoC)** in my application, so not sure if compatability could be an issue here? There are certainly no errors or information that would be lead me to beleive this is the case!

I am also using version 9.0.0 of the MediatR package.

**My basic pipeline behaviour:**

```
public class RequestTestBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        // My breakpoint is here and is never being hit by any request...
        Console.WriteLine("Custom behaviour has been hit!");

        return await next();
    }
}
```

**Registering the pipeline behaviour wtih Unity:**

```
container.RegisterMediator(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestTestBehavior<,>));

var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
assemblies.ForEach(assembly => container.RegisterMediatorHandlers(assembly));
```

**My request/handler setup:**

```
public class MyFeature
{
    public class Command : IRequest<Result<Scheme>>
    {
          // Some request properties..
    }

    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command, Result<Scheme>>
    {
        public Task<Result<Scheme>> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Some work which should only be hit once my RequestTestBehaviour handler has been hit!
        }
    }
}
```

Any clues or additional things I can try would be really helpful!

Comment: Have you seen the Unity example in the Mediatr github repo? https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/samples/MediatR.Examples.Unity/Program.cs

Comment: @JasonGoodwin God damn... so looking back through that example it looks like the example uses version Unity 5.x, whereas we were using Unity 4.x! Upgrading to latest version has done the trick! Thank you for prompting me to look back over that, was driving me nuts!!

Comment: I have posted my comment as the answer to help others in the future.